# Extract first template parameter from a template template parameter and using it inside the class?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++20, template-templates

I have the following problem: a class template A with several template parameters, I want to build a class B that takes A as template parameter and extract the first template parameter of A in order to use it in some method(think of extracting int from std::vector<int> and returning the default int{}).

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Ts>
struct A {};

template<template <typename InnerType> typename U> // <--- I'd like to use InnerType!
struct B {
  InnerType foo() { return InnerType{}; }
};

int main()
{
  B<A<int>> b;
  std::cout << b.foo() << "\n"; 

  return 0;
}
```

I knew this naive way wouldn't compile, but I can't figure out how to achieve something like that. Any tip is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't name the template parameter of a template template parameter directly. Even though it *looks* like you can name it, as you noticed that name can't actually be used.

However, you can use explicit specializations for a type that takes a single template parameter.

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct B;  // incomplete type, only needed for specialization

template<template <typename> typename U, typename InnerType>
struct B<U<InnerType>>  // specialized to be able to use InnerType
{  
  InnerType foo() { return InnerType{}; }
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qd3on7).

You could of course do something similar for templates with more than one parameter by adding specializations for those cases as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `InnerType`. It's a mnemonic. A documentation of the expected purpose for the template's first parameter. And it's completely optional. The declaration of `B` is equivalent to

```
template<template <typename> typename U> // No name
struct B {
  InnerType foo() { return InnerType{}; } // What now?
};
```

Class templates aren't types. They are factories that produce types. You can't query a factory for the *argument it will use*, because it doesn't know it yet. Furthermore, you define `B` to accepts a template as a parameter, when in fact you intend to feed it a type. That's an argument/parameter mismatch right there.

But you can query the results of the factory. If you change the definition of `B` to accept types instead of templates, you can then specialize it on types that were created from a template. This will make both the factory and the arguments it used deducible.